# Spring Boot do not display the bot response on Azure WebApp and on Skype

Tags: spring-boot, botframework

On bot framework emulator displays the foolowing messages normaly

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNUZW.png)
But when i use the same url on Bot Channels Registration, it send messages and process but it do not show the response

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPYYu.png)
Maybe the response has wrong structure i dont know:

```
public List<ResourceResponse> create(@RequestBody @Valid @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class) Activity activity,HttpServletResponse response ) {
  response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);

  System.out.println("Recebendo Mensagem");

  if (activity.type().equals(ActivityTypes.MESSAGE)){
      //preenche os dados da conversa.
      Conversa conversa = new Conversa();

      //processa a mensagem
      ConversaController conversaWatson = new ConversaController();
      conversa = conversaWatson.conversaWatson(conversa);

      //prepara activity de resposta 
      ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClientImpl(activity.serviceUrl(), credentials);
      Activity watsonActivity = SkypeActivityCreator.createWatsonActivity(activity,conversa.getRespostaWatson());
      Conversations conversation = SkypeConversationCreator.createResponseConversation(connector);
      try{
          ResourceResponse resposta =SkypeResourceResponseSender.send(conversation, activity, watsonActivity);
          responses.add(resposta);
      }catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("falha ao enviar a resposta ao usuário final:" + e.getMessage());
      }
  }
  return responses;
```

}

My Sender is

```
@Component
public class SkypeResourceResponseSender {

  public static ResourceResponse send(Conversations conversations,
      Activity requestActivity, Activity responseActivity) {
    return conversations.
        sendToConversation(requestActivity.conversation().id(), responseActivity);
  }
}
```

My pom.xml has the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.bot.connector</groupId>
  <artifactId>bot-connector</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-a1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.bot.schema</groupId>
  <artifactId>botbuilder-schema</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0-a1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What endpoint schema is it that you have plugged into your bot registration channel?

Comment: Since the app becomes a container image, the bot registrartion Channel is connected to web container service with this URL https://paifabiowebappcontainer.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Comment: This fails on the "test in webchat" blade on your bot registration channel as well correct? Are there any error messages in the channels blade or inside of the bot itself (in the logging?) Note that some logging might need to be added to get the error out.

Comment: I can see the response only when i connect with the same URL in framework emulator

Comment: The Webchat and Skype do not fail complete. They show no error, no issue on Channels. It Just don't show any response.